# Identify column in which 95% of the row sum is reached in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Rep Geno        X1         X2         X3 
1    A           5         16          1
2    A           8         10          12
3    A           9         14          21
```

I would like to sum up each row based on columns X1, X2 and X3 and then determine which column each row reached 95% of its total sum.

For example, if in the first row X1=5, X2=16, and X3=1 then the total sum would be 22 and it would have reached 95% of the total sum in column X2.

I can calculate the row sums and print them in a new column but am not sure how to identify which column 95% of the row sum is reached.

```
total = (Book2$X1 + Book2$X2 + Book2$X3 + Book2$X4+ Book2$X5)
Book3 <- cbind(Book2, total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cumulative sum (`cumsum`) function for this purpose.

Here is an example:

```
which_column <- function(x, threshold){
  which((cumsum(x) / sum(x)) >= threshold)[1]
}

selected_columns_indices <- 3:5  # Change this if analysing more columns
books2_subset <- books2[, selected_columns_indices, drop = FALSE]
apply(books2_subset, 1, which_column, threshold = 0.95)
```

The function `apply` applies the function `which_column` to each row of `book2_subset`. This is why we need to remove the unnecessary columns.

Comment: Great! This is perfect. Is there anyway to print the column name instead of the column number?

Comment: Assuming `values` is a variable containing the column numbers, you could do `colnames(books2_subset)[values]`.

Another solution would be to modify the `which_column` function to receive the column names as an argument and use the computed index to extract the appropriate column name.

Answer (score 1):

With the `tidyverse`-packages `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(k, v, 3:5) %>% 
  group_by(Rep) %>% 
  mutate(p = cumsum(v)/sum(v), reached = first(k[p > 0.95]))
```

The result:

```
    Rep Geno  k         v     p reached
  <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 A     X1        5 0.227 X2     
2     2 A     X1        8 0.267 X3     
3     3 A     X1        9 0.205 X3     
4     1 A     X2       16 0.955 X2     
5     2 A     X2       10 0.600 X3     
6     3 A     X2       14 0.523 X3     
7     1 A     X3        1 1.00  X2     
8     2 A     X3       12 1.00  X3     
9     3 A     X3       21 1.00  X3
```